# Cannot attach to tomcat container

Tags: docker, tomcat

I am running the following command:

```
docker run -itd tomcat

docker attach container-name
```

In the case above, the container starts, but when I enter the `attach` command the system goes unresponsive.

What could be the problem?

Also if I run

```
docker run -it tomcat
```

the system goes unresponsive.

Comment: Please add the error message you get.

Comment: not getting any error, the system is unresponsive . I have to open a duplicate session. but the command  docker ps -a   shows the container is running

Comment: It seems more like a problem with your docker installation. Which OS are you using? Have you tried to simply reinstall it?